# Selenium keeps opening as new User in Chrome

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've taken a look at several posts around this, but none are helping fix my problem unfortunately

Here is the code I have to open Chrome with a "Selenium" specific profile I just created. I have the latest version of ChromeDriver downloaded for Chrome 83

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Ryan\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Ryan\Workspace\Tools\Selenium\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate this issue. I can't explain why it's happening, but was able to solve by adding an additional argument. I changed the *--user-data-dir*  to point at the profile home, *User Data*. I then specified which profile I wanted with *--profile_directory*.

Here is what I ran on my computer.

```
ch_options = Options()
ch_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/jeffg/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
ch_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")   #This is the additional argument
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, chrome_options=ch_options)
```

So in your example, it would like something like this:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Ryan\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 2")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Ryan\Workspace\Tools\Selenium\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Another thing to note, if you run into this error after running the above code: ```selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir```,
close out all the other chrome windows. This fixed the error for me.